# Turning sox command line Duration into a node.js variable.

Tags: node.js, sox

I would like find the duration of an audio.wav and use the duration as a variable in node.js script.

I can get the duration of a wav on the command line using sox:

```
$ soxi -D audio.wav
```

returns:

7.870975

How is it possible to run soxi -D in a node.js file?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I solved this using a child_process:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;//require child_process.exec

exec("soxi -D /path/to/audio.wav", function(err, stdout){
    if (err){
         throw err;
}
var audioDuration = stdout * 1000; //takes audio length in seconds and converts to milliseconds
console.log("This is the Audio Duration:" + audioDuration);//Prints
});
```